# How do you cast trait objects with an Arc<Mutex<...>>?

Tags: rust, traits, smart-pointers

I am trying to call a function which takes a pointer to a `Mutex` of some trait object, and I want to be able to implement the trait for the `Mutex` of that trait object to allow treating the `Mutex` as an instance of the trait object for abstraction.

To give an example of this, imagine an `Event` listener setup as such:

```
use std::sync::{Arc, Mutex, Weak};

// Define a simple event
trait Event: Send + Sync + 'static {}
impl Event for String {}


// Define the listener interface
trait Listener<E: Event> {
    fn notify(&self, event: &E);
}

// Extend the listener interface to listenrs wrapped by a mutex
impl<E: Event> Listener<E> for Mutex<Listener<E>> {
    fn notify(&self, event: &E) {
        self.lock().unwrap().notify(event);
    }
}


// Contrived thing to listen for messages
struct Console;
impl Listener<String> for Console {
    fn notify(&self, event: &String) {
        println!("{}", event);
    }
}


// Simple function which may be called asynchronously and then sends a message
// when it is complete
fn do_stuff(l: Arc<Listener<String>>) {
    // Would normally cast to a Weak<...> and then store in a list of listneners
    // For some sort of object
    let m = String::from("I did stuff!");
    l.notify(&m);
}

fn main() {
    let l: Arc<Mutex<Console>> = Arc::new(Mutex::new(Console));

    let t1 = Arc::clone(&l) as Arc<Mutex<Listener<String>>>; //this part is ok
    // Here is where we run into issues... This *should* be equvlient to
    // do_stuff(t1), but with the corercion explicit
    let t2 = Arc::clone(&t1) as Arc<Listener<String>>;
    do_stuff(t2);

    // This is a simple, working example of it interpreting a Mutex<Listener<E>>
    // as just a Listener<E>
    let m = String::from("Somthing else...");
    (l as Arc<Mutex<Listener<String>>>).notify(&m);
}
```

([Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=e73ccb2f4966aea6d1dfd2427c3e8c7f&version=undefined))

The issue is:

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `Listener<std::string::String>: std::marker::Sized` is not satisfied in `std::sync::Mutex<Listener<std::string::String>>`
  --> src/main.rs:45:14
   |
45 |     let t2 = Arc::clone(&t1) as Arc<Listener<String>>;
   |              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ `Listener<std::string::String>` does not have a constant size known at compile-time
   |
   = help: within `std::sync::Mutex<Listener<std::string::String>>`, the trait `std::marker::Sized` is not implemented for `Listener<std::string::String>`
   = note: required because it appears within the type `std::sync::Mutex<Listener<std::string::String>>`
   = note: required for the cast to the object type `Listener<std::string::String>`
```

Why this is the case? Since an `Arc` is a pointer to data, from my understanding, it should be able to point to a `Listener<String>` which happens to be a `Listener<Mutex<String>>`.

I see at least two ways to avoid this, the first is to simply `impl Listener<String> for Mutex<Listener<String>>`, however, in the actual code this may require interdependence which should be avoided because the trait can only be implemented where the trait or structure is defined (and `Mutex` is not defined in my code).

The second is to move the `Mutex` into the `Listener` object so the caller does not need to cast it at all. This would work, and may be a better solution. Despite this, I am curious as to either why the casting proposed does not work and or what can be changed to make it work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Since an `Arc` is a pointer to data, from my understanding, it should be able to point to a `Listener<String>`

Yes, that's true. I believe your problem is that you are (accidentally?) requiring that you have a `Mutex<Listener<String>>` at some point. This is *not* valid to have because the value inside the `Mutex` isn't behind a pointer, thus making the whole type unsized.

It's fine to have an `Arc<Mutex<Listener<String>>>` though.

Instead, I'd implement the trait for a `Mutex` of *any* kind that implements the same trait. I'd do the same for references and `Box`ed trait objects of the trait as well. In all cases, I'd remove the `Sized` bound to allow for trait objects:

```
use std::sync::{Arc, Mutex};

trait Event: Send + Sync + 'static {}
impl Event for String {}

trait Listener<E: Event> {
    fn notify(&self, event: &E);
}

impl<L, E> Listener<E> for Mutex<L>
where
    L: ?Sized + Listener<E>,
    E: Event,
{
    fn notify(&self, event: &E) {
        self.lock().unwrap().notify(event);
    }
}

impl<'a, L, E> Listener<E> for &'a L
where
    L: ?Sized + Listener<E>,
    E: Event,
{
    fn notify(&self, event: &E) {
        (**self).notify(event);
    }
}

struct Console;
impl Listener<String> for Console {
    fn notify(&self, event: &String) {
        println!("{}", event);
    }
}

fn do_stuff(l: Arc<Listener<String>>) {
    let m = String::from("I did stuff!");
    l.notify(&m);
}

fn main() {
    let l: Arc<Mutex<Console>> = Arc::new(Mutex::new(Console));
    let l2 = Arc::clone(&l) as Arc<Listener<String>>;
    let l3 = Arc::clone(&l) as Arc<Listener<String>>;

    do_stuff(l);
    do_stuff(l2);

    let m = String::from("Something else...");
    l3.notify(&m);
}
```

Comment: Thank you! That makes a lot of sense. The one part that I am a little fuzzy on: What is the purpose of `impl<'a, L, E> Listener<E> for &'a L`?

Comment: @Eadword I guess I left that in there during debugging; it doesn't seem to be needed for the present code.